# Copy RAW photo to Allocation

Tags: android, allocation, android-camera2, renderscript, raw

To achieve photo stacking I have been creating Bitmap from ImageReader decoded bytes and copy into Allocation using Allocation.copyFrom(Bitmap bitmap). But Bitmap use 8 bit on color (max value 255). I want tu use Raw Data (16 bit on color). How to copy result bytes (in 16bit on pixel format) to Allocation? Render script should use ushort4 to store pixel.

Comment: I do not believe it that bitmap uses 8 bits for colors only.

Comment: Sorry for mistake. Bitmap in format RGBA_8888 use 32 bytes for pixel, 8 bytes for single color (red, green, blue or alpha channel). I want to use RAW/DNG format wchich has 16 bytes on single channel.